# extracting from DB using JDBC and creating array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc, arraylist

i'm trying  to extract from mysql database, but my code keeps throwing `nullpointerexception` and  think  its because no array is beeing created,  what am i doing wrong ? 
here's the code:  -- thanks !

```
public ArrayList<String> getRow(String quEry, String db){

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db;
                    try {
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
                    } catch (SQLException e) { 

                    }                   
                        try{
                                query = conn.prepareStatement(quEry);

                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                                try {
                                    getRow_Method_Result = query.executeQuery();
                                } catch (SQLException e) {

                                }
                    try{
                    while(getRow_Method_Result.next()){

                            row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(1));
                            row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(2));
                            row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(3));
                            row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(4));
                      } 
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }



        return row_result;
    }

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                        ConectorBaseDatos OBJ_testGetRowMethod = new ConectorBaseDatos();

                            ArrayList<String> rowListResult_ofMethos = OBJ_testGetRowMethod.getRow("SELECT * FROM `arbitros`", "fifa");

                                System.out.println(rowListResult_ofMethos.toString());
                }
```

i have tried to create this as a `String[][] array`  but since this is a little more complicated  decided to create it first as an ArrayList  then this result insert it into  `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`  but  just  STUCK  HERE

Comment: Post your error stack. The stack should tell you which line of your code threw `NullPointerException`. Also, `rowListResult_ofMethos.toString()` will not give out any useful, readable string.

Comment: @wns349, thanks,  here is the stack:  
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at modelo.ConectorBaseDatos.main(ConectorBaseDatos.java:422)
`
which is this line of code: 
`        System.out.println(rowListResult_ofMethos.toString());`

Comment: @wns349  I've been getting this error but just DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY,  I'm now learning to use  debugger  but   still in learning process  what could be the problem ?

Comment: The error says you have a problem in line 422. I have no idea what that line is, but I'm guessing it's because `rowListResult_ofMethods` is `null` and you are trying to call `toString()` on it. Maybe post your entire code instead? `ConnectorBaseDatos` class to be specific. (Kinda getting a bad feeling that the code for `ConnectorBaseDatos` will be very long as the exception was thrown from line 422...)

Comment: @wns349 yes  a little bit long,  and  its just  some other methos but  they're not related to this,  line 422 is this:
`System.out.println(rowListResult_ofMethos.toString());`
yes   I think `rowListResult_ofMethods` is  `null` but  don´t  understand why,  everything that needs to be known is here posted,  the rest of `ConnectorBaseDatos`  is irrelevant

Comment: and  I  use the  `obj.toString()` method to verify that the items are correctly  extracted from the `DataBase` I know this won't help me for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write here, as this may get a little long for comment.

`rowListResult_ofMethods` being `null` implies that your call to `OBJ_testGetRowMethod.getRow("SELECT * FROM`arbitros`", "fifa")` returned `null`.

Looking at your `public ArrayList<String> getRow(String quEry, String db)` method, I do not see where `row_result` is first initialized.

So, you should find and make sure `row_result` is initialized somewhere. (Probably something like `row_result = new ArrayList<String>()` somewhere.)

In addition, you should NEVER (I would say never, may vary for others) do nothing after catching an exception!

Do not do this:

```
try{
 while(getRow_Method_Result.next()){
    row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(1));
    row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(2));
    row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(3));
    row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(4)); 
  }
} catch(Exception e){
  //Do not leave this blank!!! you must handle exception here !
  // At least do e.printStackTrace(); to see exception during development. 
}
```

As long as connection and query to your database was successful, I'm guessing the above `row_result.add(getRow_Method_Result.getString(1));` would have thrown a `NullPointerException`. But this exception was discarded and no action was taken, as you left that part blank.

Comment: Excelent !!  yes  very dumb mistake of my part, but had been searching for this  a ton of hours  jeje   thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring `ArrayList<String> row_result`?(statically may be)
If you are initializing as `ArrayList<String> row_result=null` and you don't have any result set return then it will throw you NPE. And if you have result set then NPE will be inside very first line of while. Make sure you are initializing it as ArrayList row_result=new ArrayList();